# Shouldn't this work? Displaying an error message from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, error-handling, try-catch

So, I have a servlet as part of a RSS feed project that accepts a URL, and then it goes on to do a bunch of other things that are beyond this particular question. In the event that the user submits (via form) a blank or otherwise invalid URL, I have the following code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    URL feedURL = null;

    try {
        feedURL = new URL(request.getParameter("url"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Please go back and submit a valid URL.");
    }
```

Now instead of getting a `MalformedURLException`, I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. Am I going about this the right way? Do I have to direct the error message somewhere more specific for it to get to the user? Would I be better off using `response.sendError()`, or some other method, like JavaScript on the client side?

If it matters, the request is coming from a JSP.

As always, StackOverflow community, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you are using Chrome or Firefox, use Chome Dev Tools or Firebug to see if any parameter by the name "url" has been posted. If not, that might be a cause for the null pointer. (these tools can be accessed with the F12 key)

Comment: On which line you are getting NPE ?

Comment: The line to which the NPE seemed to reference in the stack trace was not a line number in my code. It was like 193, and I only had about 100 lines of code. So that really puzzled me, Santosh. That ever happen to you? Maybe I read the stack trace incorrectly?

Comment: And thanks, Ali. I almost forgot about Firebug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    feedURL = new URL(request.getParameter("url"));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Please go back and submit a valid URL.");
    return;
}
```

You should do a return in catch block. Nullpointer may be thrown from next lines, as feedURL will be null. If that is not the cause, please share the Nullpointer trace you get.

You should forward to an error page, from catch block in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of the `java.net.URL` class, its constructor can throw a `MalformedURLException`. This occurs when the URL is invalid.

When it is thrown, it isn't because the host machine is down (Its **503**) , or the URL path points to a missing file (Its **404**).

Common mistakes include :-
1. Leaving out a protocol
2. specifying an invalid protocol
Eg www://stackoverlfow.com
3.leaving out the ':' character

`MalformedURLException` will not be thrown if :-

1. The host name is invalid. eg www.stack-overlfow.com
2. The path is invalid. eg http://www.microsoft.com/company_secrets.html

It will also throw a `MalformedURLException` if the URL string is not parseable or contains an unsupported protocol.

You are getting `NullPointerException` means the parameter called "url" is missing from request. Double check that you are request will always have "url" as parameter.

There are plenty of ways to inform Client about something is wrong.

You can use `response.sendError() like

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

if (request.getParameter("important_parameter") == null) {
  response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Missing URL parameter");
}
```

I don't know how you can handle it using `Javascript`. But, You can also forward to same page or Error page and passing message as parameters mentioning error.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to use `sendError`, Hardik.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting the NPE in URL constructor, where it tries to parse the string sent as param. You may want to add null check before you call URL constructor. 
Also, you can also verify at the time of request submission, it ant parameter is being added in the request url named as 'url'. Since you are using doGet, you must be sending the request by clicking on some url.